# Error convert .CSV to .XML using PHP Script

Tags: php, xml, csv

I am trying to convert my CSV file to XML to import in my PrestaShop. 
I am using this script below which I got from a post. 
But it's not working.

```
function createXML(){
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
    ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);

    $inputFilename    = 'import/products_import.csv';
    $outputFilename   = 'import/productos.xml';

// Open csv to read
    $inputFile  = fopen($inputFilename, 'rt');

// Get the headers of the file
    $headers = fgetcsv($inputFile);

// Create a new dom document with pretty formatting
    $doc  = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->formatOutput   = true;

// Add a root node to the document
    $root = $doc->createElement('rows');
    $root = $doc->appendChild($root);


// Loop through each row creating a <row> node with the correct data
    while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $container = $doc->createElement('row');
        foreach($headers as $i => $header)

        {
            $child = $doc->createElement(trim($header));
            $child = $container->appendChild($child);
            $value = $doc->createTextNode($row[$i]);
            $value = $child->appendChild($value);
        }

        $root->appendChild($container);
    }

    $strxml = $doc->saveXML();
    $handle = fopen($outputFilename, "w");
    fwrite($handle, $strxml);
    fclose($handle);
    echo ('ejecutado');
}
```

The error I am getting is this:

Fatal error: Uncaught DOMException: Invalid Character Error in C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop-devel\admin\productsImportWS.php:52 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop-devel\admin\productsImportWS.php(52): DOMDocument->createElement('Product ID;Acti...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop-devel\admin\productsImportWS.php(73): createXML() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop-devel\admin\productsImportWS.php on line 52

I tried to "trim" header, but it's not working...

Comment: Seems your csv parsing expects commas but instead you have semicolons as value separator.

Comment: How can i define that?

Comment: Check fgetcsv manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response:

Apparently "fgetcsv" has a predefined type of separator, which in this case is the ",". By having a CSV, delimited by ";" it did not detect it.

I defined the delimiter as follows, in the two lines that use it:

```
$headers = fgetcsv($inputFile, '0', ';');

while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile, '0', ';')) !== FALSE)
```

By doing this, everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Characters like `&` will break your XML unless converted to `&amp;`

```
$fixed = htmlspecialchars('&');   // output &amp;
```

https://3v4l.org/K7slG

Comment: I have transformed my .csv to only 2 fields:  name   id   , and i get this error:  DOMDocument->createElement('name;id;;;;;;;;...')